# How to handle large labels (text got cropped in python barchart )

Tags: python, label, bar-chart

I have this data

```py
y1= [2232424, 2324353, 0, 8433232, 21421521, 2164216, 2761731,  752164215]
y2=[0, 32, 253, 6271, 263, 5535142, 1513153, 92512152]
```

and i plotted bar chart .. but the labels for my bar chart i rotated them to 30 degree as labels are large. but even after rotating at 30 degree the text got cropped you can see in figure below. how to figure this out

[image]

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})
    from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
    figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
    
    x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
    L = ['AAAAAA', 'BBBB', 'CCCCCC','DDDDDD', 'EEEEE', 'FFFFFFFFF', 'FGGGGG','HHHHHHHHHH']  
    y1= [2232424, 2324353, 0, 8433232, 21421521, 2164216, 2761731,  752164215]
    y2=[0, 32, 253, 6271, 263, 5535142, 1513153, 92512152]
    
    width = 0.40
    plt.bar(x - width/2, y1, width)
    plt.bar(x + width/2, y2, width)
    
    plt.legend(['one', 'two'], loc='upper right')
    plt.xticks(x, L, rotation=30, horizontalalignment='left')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote answer previous your question about converting.

In this time you need to know layout setting.

matplotlib provide powerful function for automatically setting layout.

Use tight layout(https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html)

```
# recttuple (left, bottom, right, top), default: (0, 0, 1, 1)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Also if you feel hard to use matplotlib, it is more good choice to use seaborn.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    y1     = [2232424, 2324353, 0, 8433232, 21421521, 2164216, 2761731,  752164215],
    y2     = [0, 32, 253, 6271, 263, 5535142, 1513153, 92512152],
    labels = ['AAAAAA', 'BBBB', 'CCCCCC','DDDDDD', 'EEEEE', 'FFFFFFFFF', 'FGGGGG','HHHHHHHHHH']
)).melt(id_vars=['labels'], value_vars=['y1', 'y2'])

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)

ax = sns.barplot(x='labels', y='value', hue='variable', data=data)

plt.xticks(rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```